# `Multiple radio button validation in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to do validation`in Multiple dynamic`Radio buttons`. I want to check`Radio button`is`selected` or not. if not selected then show alert and selected then go to another thing.

following code i use..

```
-(IBAction)btnNextClicked:(id)sender{
    if ([appDelegate.questions count]> i) {


        for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews)
        {
            if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                if (btn.selected)
                {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"BizVibe" message:@"Please select answer" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alert show];
                    [alert release];

                    return;
                }
                else{
                    for (int k=0; k<[[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:[[appDelegate.questions objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"question"]] count]; k++) {

                        for (UILabel *lbl in self.view.subviews)
                        {
                            if ([lbl isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                            {
                                if (lbl.tag==k)
                                {
                                    [lbl removeFromSuperview];
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews)
                        {
                            if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                            {
                                if (btn.tag==k)
                                {
                                    [btn removeFromSuperview];
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    [self LoadQuestionAnswer];
                    return;

                }
            }

        }


    }
    else{
        Term_para *termMSP = [[Term_para alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:termMSP animated:YES];
        [termMSP release];
    }
}
```

Please help me what i can do?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Im not getting u .... u want that wen either of the radio buttons are selected an alert pops up ? Please clarify ....

Comment: Can you please post some code or something which you have already tried? What is the actual issue you are facing and how are you creating radio buttons?

Comment: i want to button next clicked then check radio button is selected or not if not selected then give alert please select buttons

Comment: And what is issue in this code ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I cant help in your code because i dont know what do you want to do in that code body but you can handle a button `selected` and `UnSelected` using a `BOOL` variable and its up to your logic. See below example -

```
BOOL isSelected; // Declared it globally

-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    if(isSelected)
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"Unselected" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setTitle:@"Selected" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    isSelected = !isSelected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uibutton-tutorial-radio-buttons/) on radio button feature in iOS. Check it out. It might guide you to the right direction.

Comment: thanks but i want to check validation on next button click if radio button is selected or not